# Missing nvidia firmware upgrade issue

Tags: drivers, nvidia, nouveau

I have had warnings saying there is missing nvidia firmware & have been daily prompted with updates & reboots on my Ubuntu 18.04 system. What am I missing that is not getting upgraded.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-5.0.0-32 linux-headers-5.0.0-32-generic
  linux-image-5.0.0-32-generic linux-modules-5.0.0-32-generic
  linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-32-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-firmware
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/72.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 56.9 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 239912 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-firmware_1.173.12_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-firmware (1.173.12) over (1.173) ...
Setting up linux-firmware (1.173.12) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-36-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp107/sec2/sig-1.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp107/sec2/image-1.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp107/sec2/desc-1.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp106/sec2/sig-1.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp106/sec2/image-1.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp106/sec2/desc-1.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp104/sec2/sig-1.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp104/sec2/image-1.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp104/sec2/desc-1.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp102/sec2/sig-1.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp102/sec2/image-1.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp102/sec2/desc-1.bin for module nouveau
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-35-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp107/sec2/sig-1.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp107/sec2/image-1.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp107/sec2/desc-1.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp106/sec2/sig-1.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp106/sec2/image-1.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp106/sec2/desc-1.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp104/sec2/sig-1.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp104/sec2/image-1.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp104/sec2/desc-1.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp102/sec2/sig-1.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp102/sec2/image-1.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp102/sec2/desc-1.bin for module nouveau
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-32-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp107/sec2/sig-1.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp107/sec2/image-1.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp107/sec2/desc-1.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp106/sec2/sig-1.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp106/sec2/image-1.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp106/sec2/desc-1.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp104/sec2/sig-1.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp104/sec2/image-1.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp104/sec2/desc-1.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp102/sec2/sig-1.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp102/sec2/image-1.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gp102/sec2/desc-1.bin for module nouveau
```

Comment: Do you use nouveau driver or nvidia proprietary driver?

Comment: Well, those files don't exist for my linux-firmware 18.04 install, but without the "-1" they do.  Looks like some name change happened for the 5.0 hwe you are using.  They are just links, so you can add them yourself (copy the existing ones without the "-1", or maybe grab the linux-firmware package from 19.10(?).

Comment: BlueManCZ how would I find out if I do?